# How to fail Gitlab pipeline that calls another pipeline via API?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-api

I have 2 Gitlab repos:

1. Project A
2. Integration tests for Project A

I want to stop the pipeline / build of Project A if the integration tests fail but currently the Project A pipeline passes even if the integration tests fail.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` for Project A defines these 7 stages:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - publish
  - dev-deployment
  - staging-deployment
  - trigger-integration-tests
  - prod-deployment
```

The second last stage (`trigger-integration-tests`) kicks off the integration tests project by using the [Gitlab API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html) with `curl`:

```
trigger-integration-tests:
  stage: trigger-integration-tests
  image: ubuntu:16.04
  script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
  - "curl -X POST -F token=$INTEGRATION_TESTS_TOKEN -F variables[PROJECT_ID]=$CI_PROJECT_ID -F variables[BRANCH_NAME]=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -F ref=master https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/123/trigger/pipeline"
  allow_failure: false
  only:
  - master
```

I tried adding the `allow_failure: false` flag but that didn't help so I'm looking for more ideas.

I found the [trigger-and-wait technique](https://finestructure.co/blog/2017/12/2/gitlab-ci-pipeline-trigger-and-wait) but wasn't sure if there's a more simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

As answered on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785325/how-to-show-tests-from-another-repository-in-gitlab-ci/), you could do the following:

From the main project, using a Python/Bash script:

1. Trigger the integration tests pipeline (and capture the pipeline ID)
2. Poll the [status](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html) of the pipeline, using the captured ID (which can be `running`, `pending`, `failed`, `canceled` or `skipped`)
3. Raise an exception / error if it has failed...

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49791955/4047472) for an example python script to achieve this.